# Arduino doesn't send the entire URL to the Server

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I'm trying to send data to my computer with an Arduino Mega and Ethernet Shield every 10 seconds, but sometimes it crashes for some minutes. I looked at the Apache access log and i got it:

[Apache access log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oBMO.png)

How you can see, sometimes the Arduino sends just part of the URL (red lines in picture), not the entire URL (green lines in picture), but I don't know what is wrong. I printed the URL in serial and the monitor shows the entire URL, so I think the string isn't corrupted in Arduino, but while it is sent to the server. 
- I tried to put "client.flush()" in the code (It waits until all outgoing characters in buffer have been sent); 
 
- I tried to reduce the URL (I saw in foruns that it could be lack of Arduino memory); 

See part of my code below for more informations: (the URL is commented for reduce its lenght)

```
int sendDatatoServer(uint8_t deviceID) {
  url = "GET /Supervisorio_Energia_FPBR/insert_dados.php?";
  url +=  "ID=";
  url +=  String(deviceID);
  //url +=  "&U=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[0]);
  //url +=  "&I=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[1]);
  //url +=  "&FP=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[2]);
  //url +=  "&VA=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[3]);
  //url +=  "&VAR=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[4]);
  //url +=  "&W=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[5]);
  url +=  "&F=";
  url +=  String(vetor_resultado[6]);
  url +=  "&V1=";
  url +=  String(vetor_resultado[7]);
  //url +=  "&V2=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[8]);
  //url +=  "&V3=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[9]);
  //url +=  "&I1=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[10]);
  //url +=  "&I2=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[11]);
  //url +=  "&I3=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[12]);
  //url +=  "&DW=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[13]);
  //url +=  "&DVA=";
  //url +=  String(vetor_resultado[14]);

  if (!client.connected())                   
  {                                    
      conn();                                // Function for connection
  }   

  if (client.connected())                    // If client is connected...
  {
      client.println(url);                   // Print URL on the client
      client.flush();
      Serial.println(url);
      Serial.println("Values insert!");
      client.stop(); 
   } else {                                
      Serial.println("Without Connection!");
   } 
}
void conn()
{
  Serial.println("Connecting...");
  int i = 1;

  while(Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0)
  {
    Serial.println("Trying connection " + String(i));
    i++;
  }

  if(client.connect(server_ip, 80))          // Try connection to the server
  {
   Serial.println("Connection with server OK"); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: don't use String class. https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings

Comment: I had this issue once when I wasn't giving enough of a pause between calling and receiving data. Try increasing the time of delay by 1 second.

Comment: @Juraj, thanks, I put a lot of "client.print()" instead of creating a string and now the Arduino doesn't crash anymore. But the error still occurring.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood, thanks for your reply, after updating my code with Juraj's solution I put delay between client.print() and client.stop(), then between client.stop() and Serial.print(), and in either case it didn't work. I still getting parcial url on the server.

Comment: don't begin Ethernet before every connection. it should be done only once in setup()